# Add node navigation inside a SVG object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I want to navigate from one object/node to another smoothly inside a SVG file. To do this I used the javascript library: http://flesler.blogspot.de/2009/06/jqueryserialscroll-122-released.html that seems to work fine. The problem is that, the library seems to work only for references (#nodeId) links that are defined outside the <.svg> objects, If I use the reference link on an object that is inside the svg node, it will act incorrect, meaning it will not scroll smoothly to the defined node id.
Sample(the sample will work fine with the javascript libs referenced):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Generated by graphviz version 2.38.0 (20140413.2041)
 -->
<!-- Title: SR_GLO_Main Pages: 1 -->

<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.localScroll.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function( $ ){
   /**
    * Most jQuery.localScroll's settings, actually belong to jQuery.ScrollTo, check it's demo for an example of each option.
    * @see http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/
    * You can use EVERY single setting of jQuery.ScrollTo, in the settings hash you send to jQuery.localScroll.
    */
   
   // The default axis is 'y', but in this demo, I want to scroll both
   // You can modify any default like this
   $.localScroll.defaults.axis = 'xy';
   
   /**
    * NOTE: I use $.localScroll instead of $('#navigation').localScroll() so I
    * also affect the >> and << links. I want every link in the page to scroll.
    */
   $.localScroll({
    //target: '#content', // could be a selector or a jQuery object too.
    queue:true,
    duration:1000,
    hash:true,
    lazy:true,
    onBefore:function( e, anchor, $target ){
     // The 'this' is the settings object, can be modified
    },
    onAfter:function( anchor, settings ){
     // The 'this' contains the scrolled element (#content)
    }
   });
  });

</script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#node1">Section 1</a>

<svg width="3249pt" height="2200pt" viewBox="0.00 0.00 3249.00 2200.00" >

<g id="nodeX">
 <a xlink:href="#node1">
 <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
 </a>
 </g>

 <g id="node1">
 <circle cx="1880" cy="1580" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="red" />
 </g>
 
</svg>

</body>
```

So when clicking "Section 1", the html will center itself with a smooth transition to the red circle(with id node1) but when you press the yellow circle that has the link reference also to #node1 something is not working and the html is not focused. I want to make it work as the behaviour when pressing "Section 1"
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After some investigations I came up with some solution. So, to navigate inside a SVG from one sub-node to another we can:
1. use ecmascript inside a html file that holds the SVG node. We need to use it to interact with the SVG elements. To focus to a specific element you need to use "focusable" attributes described here: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/interact.html#focusable-attr a good sample you can find here: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/examples/navigation.svg With 'TAB' you can navigate from one menu to another. BUT this seems not to work fine, it seems that there are no browsers that support navigation focus in this manner. So I think in the future when the browsers will support it we can use easily this.
In the meantime we can use solution 2

2. Use the above javascript library to navigate from one node to another. The modifications that I added to do that:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function( $ ){
   /**
    * Most jQuery.localScroll's settings, actually belong to jQuery.ScrollTo, check it's demo for an example of each option.
    * @see http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/
    * You can use EVERY single setting of jQuery.ScrollTo, in the settings hash you send to jQuery.localScroll.
    */
   
   // The default axis is 'y', but in this demo, I want to scroll both
   // You can modify any default like this
   $.localScroll.defaults.axis = 'xy';
   
   $.localScroll({
    //target: '#content', // could be a selector or a jQuery object too.
    queue:true,
    duration:1000,
    hash:true,
    lazy:true,
    onBefore:function( e, anchor, $target ){
     // The 'this' is the settings object, can be modified
    },
    onAfter:function( anchor, settings ){
     // The 'this' contains the scrolled element (#content)
    }
   });
   
   $('#nodeX').click(function() {
    $('html, body').scrollTo(document.getElementById('node1'), 1000);
   });
  });

</script>
```